# Errors when implementing a third-party library on Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to use a third party library TTFortuneWheel to build an app. The following code is what I have added to this new project.
When I run the app, it shows this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10e5c8dd8)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var spinningWheel: TTFortuneWheel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let slices = [ FortuneWheelSlice(title: "Slice 1"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice(title: "Slice 2"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice(title: "Slice 3")]

        let frame = spinningWheel.frame
        let fortuneWheel = TTFortuneWheel(frame: frame, slices: slices)
        spinningWheel.equalSlices = true
        self.view.addSubview(fortuneWheel)
```

I have also tried the following code, which is modified from the sample of TTFortuneWheel and run successfully on the sample project, but it shows another error when running in my project: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

```
 let slices = [ FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Roller Coaster"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Try again"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Free\nticket"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Teddy\nbear"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Large popcorn"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Balloon figures"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Ferris Wheel"),
                       FortuneWheelSlice.init(title: "Pony\nRide")]
        spinningWheel.slices = slices
        spinningWheel.equalSlices = true
        spinningWheel.frameStroke.width = 0
        spinningWheel.slices.enumerated().forEach { (pair) in
            let slice = pair.element as! FortuneWheelSlice
            let offset = pair.offset
            switch offset % 4 {
            case 0: slice.style = .dark
            case 1: slice.style = .light
            case 2: slice.style = .dark
            case 3: slice.style = .light
            default: slice.style = .dark
            }
        }
```

I have tried solve these problems for a week and read throught all the files of TTFortuneWheel. I would be grateful if anyone could help me solve these errors or help me use TTFortuneWheel properly!

Call stack:

```
0   MyApp                               0x0000000106449cc7 $s13MyApp14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 311
1   MyApp                               0x000000010644a6c4 $s13MyApp14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
2   UIKitCore                           0x00000001104f343b -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1183
3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001104f3868 -[UIViewController view] + 27
4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110b2bc33 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122
5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110b2c327 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 289
6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110b3ef86 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110aeef1c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4555
8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110af40c6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1617
9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001103396d6 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 904
10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110341fce +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001103392ec -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110339c48 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1091
13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110337fba __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 782
14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110337c71 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
15  UIKitCore                           0x000000011033c9b6 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 576
16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011033d610 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011033c71d -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001103416d0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110af29a8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 514
20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001106a9dfa -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000113934125 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
22  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011393ded6 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 283
23  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011393d700 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a5c4db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a5c82ba _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
26  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011396f146 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
27  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011396edfe -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 451
28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011396f393 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 42
29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109198be1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109198463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109192b1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109192302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
33  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010cff52fe GSEventRunModal + 65
34  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110af5ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
35  MyApp                               0x000000010644b77b main + 75
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a639541 start + 1
37  ???
```

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint. Identify the line that is causing the crash

Comment: Have you try running the example here? I noticed the project supports Swift 4.2 and it hasn't been touched since last year.

Can you put the stack trace? The error seems to be related to the IBOutlet probably not being setup correctly.

Comment: @Gabox The example they provided is fine. I have added call stack to my question.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I tried. It crushes at "spinningWheel.equalSlices = true" and "spinningWheel.slices = slices" respectively.

Comment: Your cod seems a little mixed up. You have declared an `@IBOutlet` called `spinningWheel` but then you are allocating an instance in a local variable called `fortuneWheel` that you add as a subview. You set the number of slices on `spinningWheel`. It seems quite likely that you haven't connected the outlet in the storyboard, so `spinningWheel` is `nil` which cause a crash as soon as you reference it, because it is an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for replying me. The `@IBOutlet` is connected to storyboard

Comment: Then how are you instantiating this view controller? You have a classic force-unwrap-nil exception here. Either the outlet isn't connected, or the view controller instance didn't come from the storyboard.

Comment: Do you have a project we can download and check?

Comment: @Gabox yes, here's the project: https://github.com/phuanggh/MyApp.git